# Why won't this script run on startup?

Tags: bash, startup, .desktop

This script works perfectly when I launch it manually. How can I get it to run on startup? The function of the script is to get `Docky` to auto relaunch in the case of a crash.

I created the script like this:

- `gedit ~/process_monitor.sh`

Pasted in the following ([found it on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163993/how-do-i-automatically-restart-docky-after-a-crash)):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "$1" ]];then
    echo "ERROR: must specify program"
    exit 1
fi

while (( 0 == 0 ));do
    $@ &
    pid=`jobs -l | awk '{print $2}'`
    wait $pid
done
```

- Saved the file.
- Set the permission:

  ```
  chmod a+x ~/process_monitor.sh
  ```

Now, when I run it like this, it works perfectly:

```
~/process_monitor.sh docky
```

However, when I add the following to startup applications, that does not make the script launch on startup. Well, maybe it does, but the script doesn't work.

`/bin/bash ~/process_monitor.sh docky`

[image]

Basically there's some sort of graphical element that flashes on the screen for half a second, but no other sign of the script to be seen, and `Docky` does not relaunch if it's killed.

How to make this work? I'm sure it's extremely basic.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Pipe your command to a tmp file when you add it to your startup, that will let you see if you the command is executing, and when it is, drop the error message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Using paths in a .desktop file

The issue is that Startup Applications creates a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart`

In a `.desktop` file, you cannot use relative- or variable paths like `~`. Use absolute paths instead:

```
/bin/bash /absolute/path/to/process_monitor.sh docky
```

Comment: Fiksdal : As we talked about it a few minutes ago ... please give this solution a try - it most probably will solve your problem ... +1 ! :)

Comment: @cl-netbox it did :)

Comment: @Fiksdal always glad it works :)

Answer (score 0):

This is better approach

run `crontab -e`
insert this line at the bottom

```
*/2 * * * * if [ ! `pgrep docky` ] ; then /usr/bin/docky; fi
```

check if `/usr/bin/docky` command starts docky, that's it.
This will check if docky is running every 2 minutes, if not it will start docky.

Comment: This would make the assumption you're running a gui 100% of the time, or don't have a multi user system.  While that's fine for most, I find it best to not set something that will be system wide regardless of the current state.

Comment: @MRX The other answer worked perfectly, so I don't see any reason to try this.

Comment: Almost certainly, this will break from `cron` like this, since you need the `DISPLAY` -variable on GUI stuff.

Comment: Also, if Docky has crashed, I don't want to wait for up to 2 minutes for it to relaunch. It would then be quicker to launch it manually.