# How to make a daemon which checks if a program is running (at regular intervals) and starts it if it is not?

Tags: gnome, scripts, services, docky

I am on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, but I don't like the normal applications launcher so I have installed Docky, however often Docky suddenly closes and I am forced to manually restart it, so I was wondering how I could make a daemon which runs all the time in the background that would check at regular intervals if Docky is running, and if it is not, run it?

Comment: Do you not want to run a script kicked off by a cron job every 10-15 minutes to check it?

Comment: @Terrance: That would probably be good.

Comment: OK, let me throw something together for you here.  :)

Comment: Simple task, not too difficult to implement. What are requirements ?

Comment: I knew, because I answered this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/751465/why-wont-this-script-run-on-startup/751480#751480

Comment: Since your question is a duplicate, I've posted an answer on the dupe question. http://askubuntu.com/a/752531/295286

Comment: What about supervisord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script anywhere you want it to be, preferably in your home directory.  I like to call mine, `check_docky.bsh`.  In your script, do the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -ef | grep -i docky.exe | grep -v grep >/dev/null

case $? in
1) sh -c "mono /usr/lib/docky/Docky.exe";;
0) exit 0;;
esac
```

In the above script, the `ps -ef | grep` will look to see if `Docky` is running.  If it is not running the exit code that gets returned is `1`, so then the case statement would relaunch `Docky` automatically.  Else, the script would exit normally with a code `0`.

Make sure the script is executable:

```
chmod +x check_docky.bsh
```

Then create a `cron` job for the script.

First, run `crontab` as you:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Then as a new entry add the following so that it will check every 10 minutes starting at `:00` of the hour:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/10 * * * * /home/<username>/check_docky.bsh
```

To show that this command works:

```
~$ ps -ef | grep wookie | grep -v grep
~$ echo $?
1
~$ ps -ef | grep wookie
terrance  20978  6976  0 13:53 pts/17   00:00:00 grep --color=auto wookie
~$ echo $?
0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer is flawed as the exit code use will always be 0 due to `grep -v grep` always matching. You need to move that statement after `ps -ef | grep -v grep` or something like that.

Comment: @13m5 Check edit.  Please test before you comment.

Comment: @13m5 There is nothing wrong with that statement.  I don't write answers that I don't test.  `grep -v grep` makes it so that grep doesn't find itself as a process because technically it is a process at the moment.  I know that there are other ways to do this, but this method works fine.